# Jquery Cycle + Jcarousel slideshow thumbs not loading?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, jquery-cycle

I'm working on combining jquery cycle and jcarousel to make a slideshow. It works great in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, yet in IE the thumbnails are not loading.

I'm guessing it has something to do with how the images in the pager are generated and then jcarousel just isnt proccessing that in IE but I 'm not sure. I feel like I'm very close to getting this slideshow to work, yet I need to figure out why it is failing in IE.

Here is the html code:

```
<!-- PHOTO SLIDESHOW CONTROLS -->                   
    <div id="photo-slideshow-controls">

        <a id="prev-btn" href="#">Prev</a> 
        <a id="next-btn" href="#">Next</a>
        <a id="play" href="#">Play</a> 
        <a id="pause" href="#">Pause</a>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div><!--/PHOTO SLIDESHOW CONTROLS -->


    <!-- PHOTO SLIDESHOW -->
    <div id="advanced-slideshow">
        <img src="assets/bridge-towers.jpg" width="593" height="474" alt="Bridge Towers" name="John Doe" />
        <img src="assets/dixie-lan-bbq.jpg" width="632" height="474" alt="BBQ" name="Jane Doe l Associated Press" />
        <img src="assets/downtown-overlook.jpg" width="632" height="421" alt="Overlooking Downtown Kansas City" name="Joel Johns l GardnerEDGE" />
        <img src="assets/downtown-skyline.jpg" width="474" height="219" alt="Downtown Kansas City Skyline" name="Brett Jankord" />
        <img src="assets/liberty-tower.jpg" width="356" height="474" alt="Liberty Tower" name="Steve Hengeli" />
        <img src="assets/plaza-fountain.jpg" width="632" height="468" alt="Plaza Fountain" name="Kevin Wright l GardnerEDGE" />
        <img src="assets/sprint-center.jpg" width="632" height="371" alt="Sprint Center" name="John Doe" />
        <img src="assets/union-station.jpg" width="632" height="416" alt="Union Station at night" name="Jane Doe" />
        <img src="assets/western-auto.jpg" width="632" height="474" alt="Western Auto" name="Kevin Wright l GardnerEDGE" />
        <img src="assets/bridge-towers.jpg" width="593" height="474" alt="Bridge Towers" name="John Doe" />
        <img src="assets/dixie-lan-bbq.jpg" width="632" height="474" alt="BBQ" name="Jane Doe l Associated Press" />
        <img src="assets/downtown-overlook.jpg" width="632" height="421" alt="Overlooking Downtown Kansas City" name="Joel Johns l GardnerEDGE" />
        <img src="assets/downtown-skyline.jpg" width="474" height="219" alt="Downtown Kansas City Skyline" name="Brett Jankord" />
    </div><!--/PHOTO SLIDESHOW -->


    <div id="photo-credit"></div>


    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    </ul>

    <div class="clear"></div>


    <div id="slideshow-caption"></div>
```

So cycle is sliding the imgs in div#advanced-slideshow and then creates a thumbnail pager based off of those images in ul#mycarousel. Then jcarousel uses the list items in ul#mycarousel to build the carousel. Works like a charm in FF, Chrome, Safari but I cant figure out how to get it to work in IE.

Here is the JS code:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
// Adds ability to link to specifics slides    
var index = 0, hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash) {
    index = /\d+/.exec(hash)[0];
    index = (parseInt(index) || 1) - 1; // slides are zero-based
}

// Setup for Cycle Plugin
$('#advanced-slideshow').cycle({ 
prev:   '#prev-btn', 
next:   '#next-btn', 
timeout: 0, 
before: onBefore,
startingSlide: index,
pager:  '#mycarousel', 
    // callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="75" height="75" /></a></li>'; 
    } 
}); 



//Pauses slideshow
$('#pause').click(function() { $('#photo-slideshow').cycle('pause'); return false; });

//Instantly resumes slidesshow
$('#play').click(function() { $('#photo-slideshow').cycle('resume', true); });


/* Delayed resumes slideshow
$('#play').click(function() { $('#photo-slideshow').cycle('resume'); return false; });
*/




function onBefore(curr,next,opts) {


    // Centers the image
    var $slide = $(next);
    var w = $slide.outerWidth();
    var h = $slide.outerHeight();
    $slide.css({
        marginTop: (476 - h) / 2,
        marginLeft: (634 - w) / 2
    });


    // Centers the DIV vertically!!!!   
    var divHeight = 476;
    var theImageHeight = $slide.outerHeight();
    var newTopMargin = (divHeight - theImageHeight) / 2;
    if(theImageHeight > 476){
        $('#advanced-slideshow').css({
            marginTop: newTopMargin
        });
    }


    // Adds caption and credit line
    $('#photo-credit').html('<p>' + "Photo By: "  + this.name + '</p>') 

    $('#slideshow-caption').html(this.alt); 


    // Adds ability to link to certain slides
    {window.location.hash = opts.currSlide + 1;}


};


//jCarousel 
$('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    scroll: 5,
    visible: 5,
});
```

}); // END

Here is a link to what I have so far. [Demo](http://www.webphibian.com/standards/slideshows/new-slideshow.php)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any chance I can take a look at your demo code, please? The links are no longer working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user over at the jquery forums pointed out I had an extra ,
I needed to change visbile: 5, to visible: 5

It worked great and now the slideshow works in IE. I tested IE 6 through IE 8. It tends to work better in IE if you but the JS code up in the head tag rather than at the end of the page. I thought I'd share this in case anyone else is wanting to use this.